# How to use resource model delete?

Tags: magento2, resource-model

I want to delete an entry in my custom module table, in a similar way to this select:

```
    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
        ['*' => $this->getMainTable()]
    )->where(
        'quote_ref = ?',
        $quote_ref
    );

    $data = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($select);
```

I am using the following code:

```
    public function deleteByRef($quote_ref = null)
    {
        $delete = $this->getConnection()->delete();
}
```

And getting the following error:

1 exception(s):

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Missing argument 1 for Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::delete(), called in C:\laragon\www\websitestore\app\code\Website\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Data.php on line 43 and defined in C:\laragon\www\websitestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php on line 650

How can I pass parameters to the delete method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$myTable = $resource->getTableName('mytable');

$connection->delete(
    $myTable,
    ['order_id = ?' => 10000]
);
return;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

If we take a look:

**vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/AdapterInterface.php**

```
    /**
     * Deletes table rows based on a WHERE clause.
     *
     * @param  mixed        $table The table to update.
     * @param  mixed        $where DELETE WHERE clause(s).
     * @return int          The number of affected rows.
     */
    public function delete($table, $where = '');
```

As we can see, `delete` method needs at least one argument. In our case, we can try:

```
 $this->getConnection()->delete(
                $this->getMainTable(),
                ['quote_ref = ?', $quote_ref]
            );
```

Comment: I got an error, Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound, query was: DELETE FROM `ghm_udropship_vendor_shipping` WHERE (vendor_id = ? ) AND (1).
 Can you please let me know.

Comment: You need to have the array key `quote_ref = ?` and the value `$quote_ref` in this example.
Otherwise it treats the array as a list of different where clauses